# Kotlin labmda invoke alternatve

Tags: kotlin, lambda, callback, invoke

Assume we have the following code:

```
fun interface A {
    fun a()
}

interface B {
    fun b(a: A)
}

fun x(callback: A.() -> Unit) = object : B {
    override fun b(a: A) {
        a.callback()
        //callback.invoke(a)
    }
}
```

Why we can use a.callback() instead of callback.invoke(a)
What is the meaning of such a syntax? Can't find it in official documentation.
And yes, here a.callback() is also equivalent to (a as A).callback()

Comment: Because `callback` is of type `A.() -> Unit`, meaning it is an extension function on `A`. You can read about it in the documentation here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html#function-literals-with-receiver

Comment: Also see https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html#invoking-a-function-type-instance

Answer (score 1):

The type of `callback` is a function type with a receiver. From the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html#function-types):

> Function types can optionally have an additional **receiver** type, which is specified before the dot in the notation: the type `A.(B) -> C` represents functions that can be called on a receiver object `A` with a parameter `B` and return a value `C`.

`callback` is of type `A.() -> Unit`, so it can be called on an instance of `A` (i.e. the parameter `a`).

This is similar to how you normally call extension functions. `callback` here acts like an extension function on `A` (because its type is `A.() -> Unit`), so you can call it like an extension function inside `x`.